# Unable to read or delete file on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security, administrator

On my Windows 10 machine (running latest version) I have a file that I need to delete that was created by Microsoft Visual Studio.

Visual Studio does not allow me to delete it and now fails when attempting to delete the file. When using explorer (running as admin) I still cannot read or delete the file.

I am the only user on my machine so I'm struggling to see how I can remove this file. When I look at the file's properties it is as per the attached.

[image]

Clicking the "Advanced" button and any option thereafter yields the following
[image]

Comment: Sounds like the path is longer than 255 chars. Using explorer, navigate into the path at least 5 or 6 directories deep, then click in the addressbar so you can type in there. Then type `subst j: .` A command window will flash open and closed. Now there's a J drive. Go there and see if you can delete the folder with everything in there. If so, you can now also delete the remaining folders.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for the feedback. My file is at "C:\Users\bbbsb\Source\Repos\FHIRToolbox\TBoxAlpha\bin\Debug" so that's not the issue in this case

Comment: If you press advanced, can you then take ownership of the file? that should allow you to edit the security settings.

Comment: There are multiple approaches here I would try. The first thing I'd try is to run PowerShell as admin and `Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\bbbsb\Source\Repos\FHIRToolbox\TBoxAlpha\bin\Debug‌\FHIRToolbox.exe -Force -Confirm`. If that does not work, too, I'd try to restart Windows into safe mode and try it there. If that (and LPChip's approaches) does not help, too, I'm a bit out of ideas (if we're not considering the trouble of accessing the file with a live system).

Comment: @LPChip thanks for the further suggestion, still no joy. I have updated the info in the question.

Comment: What if you navigate a few folders down, go into security, advanced, then check: `replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permissions from this object`? That should reset the permissions on your file.

Comment: @LPChip thanks once again - still get a security error.

Comment: Go up levels until you don't get it anymore. Or does it start propagating and then when it reaches the file, it gives an error? If that's the case, then the only way to fix this, is to format your drive. Oh, one more thing. sounds weird, but try renaming the file to something else.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your file has lost its ACL information. The only way I know how to reset it, is by going to a higher level in your folder structure, and push down its permissions with inheritable permiisions.

To do so, right click the folder one or two levels up, go to properties, security.

Go into advanced security, press the shield at the bottom to allow changes, then check:

```
[v] replace all child object permission entries with inheritable
    permissions from this object.
```

Hit apply and see how explorer changes the configuration of all folders.

Once done, see if you can now open/delete that file.

Comment: This fails with a similar security message.

Comment: @BENBUN You need to use the built-in Administrator account if you are not using an user that is in the Administrators user group.  This cannot be solved without Administrator permissions

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1**

 Open Command Prompt by running it as an administrator then type in there-

```
del /f filename
```

**METHOD 2**

Use of a third party software : LockHunter (I have used it many times)

Hope this helps :)
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how or why but on discussion with a colleague off-line he suggested the following that appears to have solved the problem.

I ran a "chkdsk /sdcleanup" and the issue seemed to resolve itself.

Not sure why it happened or how this fixed it - but it did.